# Is it possible to find unmapped properties in System.Text.Json?

Tags: c#, jsonserializer, system.text.json

Is it possible to find unmapped properties with the `System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer`?

I'm accessing an API which returns an array of documents. I want to know if there is a way to *know* if there is an property in the json document which is not mapped by my C# type. At best a method that returns a list of unmapped properties.

### Example

**JSON Document**

```
{
    "docs": [
        {
            "foo": "a",
            "bar": "b",
            "baz": "c",
        }
    ]
}
```

**C# types**

```
public class Wrapper 
{
    [JsonPropertyName("docs")]
    public List<MyDocument> Documents { get; set; }
}

public class MyDocument 
{
    [JsonPropertyName("foo")]
    public string Foo { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("baz")]
    public string Baz { get; set; }
}
```

**Parser**

```
using System.Text.Json;

var body = "{ ... }";
var documents = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Documents>(body);

List<JsonElement> unmappedProperties 
    = JsonSerializer.FindUnmappedProperties<Document>(body);
```

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of [Is it possible to catch somehow the remainder of JSON data that didn't match any POCO properties while deserializing?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63227109/3744182), agree?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use [`[JsonExtensionData]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.jsonextensiondataattribute?view=net-5.0), for example:

```
public class MyDocument 
{
    [JsonPropertyName("foo")]
    public string Foo { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("baz")]
    public string Baz { get; set; }

    [JsonExtensionData]
    public Dictionary<string, object> ExtensionData { get; set; }
}
```

The property "bar" will be serialized to the `ExtensionData` property.

You need .NET Core 3+ or .NET 5+  (or .NET framework 4.6.1 / NET Standard 2.0, see comment of Jimi)

See [How to handle overflow JSON with System.Text.Json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-handle-overflow)

To find all unmapped properties you need to add the property with `[JsonExtensionData]` to all classes that get serialized. Also you need to loop over it (maybe with reflection). It's a bit cumbersome, but it works.

Comment: It's also available in .Net Framework with the [System.Text.Json 5.0.2](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Text.Json/5.0.2) package.

Comment: Great addition Jimi :)